# What kind of wood slabs did I just bring home?

Tags: wood

I live in Minnesota. I saw these slabs just sitting out there at a local school dump a couple days ago so I brought a few home.

A few of them will be good for hammerschlagen and the big ones I might be able to make a coffee table out of. Anyone know what kind of wood this is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Think it is a mix.  Some maple, a piece of poplar/birch, and something else.  They might have been left on the wet ground for too long to be useful.

Comment: If you learn which is which then you don't waste effort picking up the cheap stuff...

Comment: All these years I thought hammering nails into wood was work, now I find out it is a game.

Comment: Those are rounds, not slabs. Get your hands on Hoadly's **Identifying Wood** via interlibrary loan (or buy a copy) if you *really* want to know species based on just the wood, but your coffee table will be full of cracks/checks given the way those are cut.

Comment: It looks weathered enough that it would not be worth making furniture with. Good for burning.

Comment: I hope you didn't haul these very far. Transportating fresh logs without knowing their back story is a good way to spread invasive species.

Comment: Identifying wood species from a picture is difficult enough that it's off-topic at [woodworking.se]. Talk to someone local if the species matters, otherwise, just make the most of what you've got and call it good.